# remove last part of string following '&&&' with JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use a regex in JS to remove the last part of a string.  This substring starts with `&&&`, is followed by something not `&&&`, and ends with `.pdf`.

So, for example, the final regex should take a string like:

```
parent&&&child&&&grandchild.pdf
```

and match

```
parent&&&child
```

I'm not that great with regex's, so my best effort has been something like:

```
.*?(?:&&&.*\.pdf)
```

Which matches the whole string.  Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this greedy regex either in `replace` or in `match`:

```js
var s = 'parent&&&child&&&grandchild.pdf';

// using replace
var r = s.replace(/(.*)&&&.*\.pdf$/, '$1');

console.log(r);
//=> parent&&&child

// using match
var m = s.match(/(.*)&&&.*\.pdf$/)
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
  //=> parent&&&child
}
```

By using **greedy pattern** `.*` before `&&&` we make sure to match **last instance of `&&&` in input.

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove the last portion, so replace it

```js
var str = "parent&&&child&&&grandchild.pdf"
var result = str.replace(/&&&[^&]+\.pdf$/, '')
console.log(result)
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is, if the grandchild string contains a single `&` it breaks.

Comment: @DavidJ. well the sample string did not so I made an assumption. Yeah it is not the best, but can do the job in certain situations. Personally I would split and pop.

Comment: You're right, split and pop is probably more efficient.  Thanks for the tip.